# Move an Image in circular path in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am having an Image, I wanted to move it in circular path `onClick()` event of button without animation,

I don't know how to do it.. Any help??

---

This is my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyAnimation animation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    animation =new MyAnimation ();

}
```

and I am using code given by you as

```
public class MyAnimation extends Animation {
float cx,cy,prevX,prevY,r;

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    float angle = (float) (interpolatedTime * 2 * Math.PI);
    // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
    float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angle)) ; 
    float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angle));

    float dx = prevX - x;
    float dy = prevY - y;

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;

    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
}
```

}

And this is my xml of image which i wanted to move in circular shape.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myanimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: If you want to manually revolve the view - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34898135/4440874

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you have two options here: either you create a custom animation, or you create your ImageView and then use a surface to draw it along the path yourself.

The first option is much easier, and will probably give better results given that in the Animation class the timing is handled for you with `Interpolators` (Linear time, start fast, end normal, etc). I strongly advice you to write the custom animation, as I don't see why you would not want to use the Animation class (animating an image is exactly what you want).

**Edit**: I took some time and implemented the following. It's not spotless, but does animate the image in a circular path.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation anim = new MyAnimation(image, 100);
                anim.setDuration(3000);
                image.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Animation class:

```
public class MyAnimation extends Animation {

    private View view;
    private float cx, cy;           // center x,y position of circular path
    private float prevX, prevY;     // previous x,y position of image during animation
    private float r;                // radius of circle
    private float prevDx, prevDy;


    /**
     * @param view - View that will be animated
     * @param r - radius of circular path
     */
    public MyAnimation(View view, float r){
        this.view = view;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        // calculate position of image center
        int cxImage = width / 2;
        int cyImage = height / 2;
        cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
        cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

        // set previous position to center
        prevX = cx;
        prevY = cy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if(interpolatedTime == 0){
            t.getMatrix().setTranslate(prevDx, prevDy);
            return;
        }

        float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;
        float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

        // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
        float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
        float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));


        float dx = prevX - x;
        float dy = prevY - y;

        prevX = x;
        prevY = y;

        prevDx = dx;
        prevDy = dy;


        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
    }
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You probably need to tweak it here and there to get what you want exactly, but this can be a basis for that.

Comment: THnx for suggestion.. But  it is rotate animation.... I want to move my image in circular path not in rotation... So can you help me out in this??

Comment: Its not moving... I think I am doing some mistake in my code to call MyAnimation class. Could you upload full code??

Thnx in advance

Comment: No, I Can't. I can try to help you solve your problem though. Can you show the exact code you have now for the MyAnimation class, and how you use it?

Comment: And how we will set number of rotation. Suppose i want to rotate image in circular path 6 times continuously ?I checked with anim.setRepeatCount(10); but problem is UI. After every rotation its coming at its parent position, then again start.

Comment: @BlueGreen  : Were you able to fix it? Upon completing an rotation, it goes back to center of circle and then start again.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the first if: `if(interpolatedTime == 0)` which returns. Removing this might help. Otherwise, you might need to play with the `fillBefore` and `fillAfter` values (don't forget `fillEnabled`).

Comment: Not done with fillbefore, fillAfter, fillEnabled... is there any other idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to investigate. You should debug the app to see what happens (is initialize called more than once? maybe it should call it's parent). I would also add logs to the `applyTransformation()` call and print the interpolatedTime (it should go from 0 to 100, for each repeat). Did you remove the `if()` check? If that does not work, you can put a breakpoint in the `onDraw()` of the ImageView and check who calls it (something is redrawing the image between the repeats).

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure `onDraw()` is called automatically after `applyTransformation()`. If `interpolatedTime == 0` is true, it will not transform anything, so it makes sense it goes back to the center. Try to remove this first.

Comment: it working perfect.Image is moved in circular path as per our radius.but is it possible to move this image continueous.I'll try to set anim.setRepeatcount() than it's working fine but while image is complete one round than image is stop moving for second.Is it possible to solve this.

Comment: added a flag to switch direction:`if (isClockwise) { x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad)); y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad)); } else { y = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad)); x = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad)); }`

Comment: remove the lag when repeatCount > 1 with:                                                         `anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());`

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie i think you are the right person to fix my bug. please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241877/image-moving-animation-is-not-working

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie can u please explain the logic behind 
        "float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;"