# How to find if ACTION_MOVE touch event is on a circular path: Android

Tags: android, math, touch

I am moving an image around a circle via touch events. 
I want the user to touch the image and when the user drags this image around the cirle, it moves, otherwise it doesn't move.

Could someone please help with the math on how to check if the finger in moving along the circle or not and them move the image accordingly.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I am trying to revolve an image around a circle. It is already placed on the circle edge.

But on touch and move actions it takes it self as the centre and then starts moving around a defined radius.

could someone pls see the code and let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                        mInitialX = event.getX();
                        mInitialY = event.getY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    mEndX = event.getX();
                    mEndY = event.getY();

                    float deltaX = mEndX - mInitialX;
                    float deltaY = mEndY - mInitialY;
                    double angleInDegrees = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;

                    mInitialX = mEndX;
                    mInitialY = mEndY;

                    mCurrTempIndicator.setRotation((float)angleInDegrees);
                    mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationX((float)(310*(Math.cos(angleInDegrees))));
                    mCurrTempIndicator.setTranslationY((float)(310*(Math.sin(angleInDegrees))));




                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    allowRotating = true;
                    break;
            }



            return true;
        }
```

Comment: compute the distance between the circle's center and the point where touch event occurs. if its in a range r-delta, r+delta then you are on the circle path

Comment: yes that would work. But how do i find the centre of the circle in coordinates for the calculation

Comment: you dont know where you draw your circle?

Comment: i am loading an image for the circle. (Sorry for the confusion) but not sure of the exact location in coordinates. is there a way to find that out through the imageview that is loaded inside onCreate()?

Comment: so why are you using imageview and not drawing the Bitmap directly?

Comment: we want different images for the background and hence the image

Comment: so draw different Bitmaps, whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float dx = event.getX() - circleCenterX
float dy = event.getY() - circleCenterY;

// r is now the radius of the touch event, you can compare it with the radius of your circle to find out if it's close enough
float r = FloatMath.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

if(r > circleRadius - 10 && r < circleRadius + 10){
    // a is now the angle between the center point and the touch point in radians. With 0 being 3 o'clock, -/+PI being 9 o'clock -PI/2 at 12 o'clock and +PI/2 at 6 o'clock.
    float a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. one question, I have a image as the circle and not sure of the centre of the circle on the screen. is it possible to find the centre of the image when the image is loaded in onCreate()

Comment: Measure it manually in an image editor and save those values somewhere would be easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer. I made some changes to make it work properly. In this I'm making an ImageView to revolve around a fixed center point meaning ImageView will move along the circumference of the circle.

```
double centerX, centerY; //Center coordinates of the circle
int radius; //Set the radius in pixels

//The view which will revolve on the circumference of the circle
imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add); //Set your view icon
imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

//Setting the imageView on the circumference of the circle
imageView.setTranslationX(centerX + radius);
imageView.setTranslationY(centerY);

//Add imageview to the parent layout dynamically(choice)
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);


imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            double dx = motionEvent.getRawX() - centerX;
            double dy = motionEvent.getRawY() - centerY; //Also subtract toolbar height and status bar height if applicable

            //Distance between user's point of touch and circle center
            double distance = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

            if (distance > radius - 200 && distance < radius + 200) {
                double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

                //Getting the point on the circumference of the circle using the angle and the radius
                double x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
                double y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);

                //Finally move the view along the circimference of the circle as the user drags the view
                imageView.animate().y((float) y).x((float) x).setDuration(0).start();
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```