# Android: animating an image circularly around a point infinite loop

Tags: android, animation, geometry

I need to move a search icon circularly around a point in an infinite loop to simulate an ongoing search (until the user stops the search).
I followed the answer provided to the question at this link:
[Move an Image in circular path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281265/move-an-image-in-circular-path-in-android).

I added this two rows to my code as I need the animation to be inifinite:

```
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

The problem is that when the first circular loop ends, the icon returns for a frame to its original position (the position declared in the xml) and then returns back to what should be the next correct position of the loop.

[image: Circular path]

How can I have a smooth animation with the icon not passing from its original centered position?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will rotate the image view circularly around its center for infinite period of time without starting the icon returning back to its original position.

```
private static final float ROTATE_FROM = 00.0f;
private static final float ROTATE_TO = 360.0f;
private static final int DURATION = 1000;

protected void startLoading(ImageView iv) {
    RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM,
            ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    r.setDuration(DURATION);
    r.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    r.setFillAfter(true);
    r.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    iv.startAnimation(r);
}
```