# Image moving animation is not working

Tags: android, android-animation

Currently i'm doing simple game like shell game. It's working good in Lollipop,Marshmallow,Nougat and KitKat 4.4.2 but not working in other KitKat version device and Jellybean.[image]

Moving animation code is

```
public class BottomLeftToRightAnimation extends Animation {
private View view;
private float prevX,prevY;
private float cx,cy;
private float prevDx,prevDy;
private float r;
public BottomLeftToRightAnimation(View view,float r){
    this.view = view;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true; // animation will change the view bounds
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    // center position of image
    int cxImage = width/2;
    int cyImage = height/2;
    cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
    cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

    //starting point of image rotation
    prevX = cx+r;
    prevY = cy;
}

// helps to get transformation between the interpolatedTime 0 to 1
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    if (interpolatedTime == 0){
        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(prevDx,prevDy);
        return;
    }
    float angD = (interpolatedTime * -180f) % 180;
    float angR = (float) Math.toRadians(angD);

    float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angR));
    float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angR)/1.5);

    float dx = prevX - x;
    float dy = prevY - y;

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;

    prevDx = dx;
    prevDy = dy;
    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx,dy);
}
}
```

This same way i wrote code for all rotation. I saw many question like same problem.The suggested to use `basket[1].setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);` or `basket[1].setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);` but it doesn't fix the issue.Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: What you want to achieve, and what goes wrong on your way?

Comment: i want my image have to move without glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the background layer with a color e.g. #FFFFFF to remove the ghost image left behind by the animation.