# How to move Aeroplane picture in circle in android programmatically?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I know how to move the image in circle in android while using this source code[Move image in circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281265/move-an-image-in-circular-path-in-android)
This code is perfect in moving imageview in circle but i want to move aeroplane picture in circle and i want that it should be look like real motion of airplane. Can any one help me

Comment: what is the difference between `move the imageview in circle` and `move aeroplane picture in circle`? How exactly does `real motion of airplane` look? It is not clear.

Comment: Exactly what the difference between `move the imageview in circle and move aeroplane picture in circle` : /

Comment: you can apply circular animation  and if by real motion you mean some special effects then you can use gif image

Comment: @UsmanRana Look sir, i have an airplane  picture and i can move it in circle, but the problem is that it does not follow the shape of circle, You know it should like the real airplane move in circle, but here only the image of airplane move in circle and it does not look like real movement in circle

Comment: for that case airplane should turn also while moving in circle, right? but you have 2D image not a 3D model like unity games. For better view you can use svg or gif image.

Comment: @UsmanRana So, what can i use for this purpose can i convert my airplane picture to gif and then use same code to move?

Comment: you need to make collection of images that different angles like turning, turning a bit more and so on to complete a cycle in circular rotation and you can join those image to make a gif online OR use those images in animation-list. https://ezgif.com/maker it may help you

Answer (score -2):

```
public class AnimationView extends View {

    Paint paint;
    Bitmap bm;
    int bm_offsetX, bm_offsetY;
    Path animPath;
    PathMeasure pathMeasure;
    float pathLength;
    float step;   //distance each step
    float distance;  //distance moved
    float[] pos;
    float[] tan;
    Matrix matrix;

    public AnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initMyView();
    }

    public AnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initMyView();
    }

    public AnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initMyView();
    }

    public void initMyView(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{6,6}, (float)2.0);

        paint.setPathEffect(dashPath);

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.airplane);
        bm_offsetX = bm.getWidth()/2;
        bm_offsetY = bm.getHeight()/2;

        animPath = new Path();
        animPath.addCircle(600, 600, 500, Path.Direction.CW);
        animPath.close();

        pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(animPath, false);
        pathLength = pathMeasure.getLength();

        step = 1;
        distance = 0;
        pos = new float[2];
        tan = new float[2];

        matrix = new Matrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawPath(animPath, paint);

        if(distance < pathLength){
            pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, pos, tan);

            matrix.reset();
            float degrees = (float)(Math.atan2(tan[0], tan[1])*0.0/Math.PI);
            matrix.postRotate(degrees, bm_offsetX, bm_offsetY);
            matrix.postTranslate(pos[0]-bm_offsetX, pos[1]-bm_offsetY);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, matrix, null);

            distance += step;
        }else{
            distance = 0;
        }

        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.buildrepo.circlerotation.MainActivity">

    <com.buildrepo.circlerotation.AnimationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>